# Is there a quicker way to write conditional statements?

Tags: javascript, syntactic-sugar

I have a statement like this:

```
 if(window.location.hash != '' && window.location.hash != '#all' && window.location.hash != '#')
```

Can I write it so I only have to mention `window.location.hash` once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the obvious way to do this is:

```
var h = window.location.hash;
if (h != '' && h != '#all' && h != '#')
```

Comment: I tend to use local variables this way a lot. It makes debugging easier, too.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the in operator and an object literal:

```
if (!(window.location.hash in {'':0, '#all':0, '#':0}))
```

this works by testing the keys of the object (the 0's are just filler).

Also note that this may break if you are messing with `object`'s prototype

Comment: A solution using arrays would be neater (no need for the filler 0s), but IE doesn't have `indexOf`, so I suppose this is better

Comment: Do you really need the `!`? Don't the `0` s accomplish that? A quick [search](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6557) suggested using `1` in a simple "or" situation, so I'm guessing the `0` would negate it?

Comment: @Isaac the 0's aren't significant, `in` just checks the keys.

Comment: So they could be `1` s as well, in either case?

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression? Not so readable, but concise enough:

```
if (/^(|#|#all)$/.test(window.location.hash)) {
    // ...
}
```

This also works:

```
if (window.location.hash.match(/^(|#|#all)$/)) {
    // ...
}
```

... but it's less efficient, per Ken's comment.

Comment: To be perfectly accurate, the second example should use `search` instead of `match`, and both should test that the value == -1.  String's `search` method is comparable to RegExp's `test` method, whereas its `match` method is comparable to RegExp's `exec` method.  `match` and `exec` are slower but give more information (or `null` on no match), whereas `search` and `test` simply give the index in the string at which the first match begins (or -1 on no match).

Comment: `RegExp.test` returns a boolean, not an index. I agree with the rest of your comment, though. My second example is slightly inefficient, but more readable than the alternative you propose - and brevity was the point of the question, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf` for newer browsers, and supply an implementation for older browsers which you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
// return value of -1 indicates hash wasn't found
["", "#all", "#"].indexOf(window.location.hash)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition, because besides quite good variety of *do not repeat yourself* approaches, nobody mentioned that:

> In browsers, `window` is `Global`
>   object, so cut it off, if you dont
>   have another property named
>   `"location"` in the current scope
>   (unlikely). `location.hash` is enough

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good to check on length since the first character always is an hash.

```
var h = location.hash;
if ( h.length > 1 && h != '#top' )
```